# How do i reset to my earlier commit?

Tags: git

I have used multiple `resets` unintelligently and i am now all over the place in my git repository. Here is the output from `reflog` and my question is how can i go to this commit `modify GBSX_script for PstI/MspI enzyme`?

```
a4c0b87 HEAD@{0}: commit: add few changes
a465ae2 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD@{8}
31a3dd2 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD@{6}
7b4d404 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD@{2}
a465ae2 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD@{3}
498d4db HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
7b4d404 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD^
498d4db HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD^
a465ae2 HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD^
31a3dd2 HEAD@{9}: commit: modify GBSX_script for PstI/MspI enzyme
a465ae2 HEAD@{10}: commit: modify GBSX_script for ApeKI enzyme
498d4db HEAD@{11}: commit: add chr txt file for Aspen genome
7b4d404 HEAD@{12}: reset: moving to HEAD^
04aa5f6 HEAD@{13}: reset: moving to HEAD^^
563b93a HEAD@{14}: reset: moving to HEAD^
bc782a6 HEAD@{15}: commit: mend
563b93a HEAD@{16}: commit: add chr txt file for Aspen genome
56884a1 HEAD@{17}: commit: modify GBSX script for ApeK1 for Aspen
04aa5f6 HEAD@{18}: commit: modify chr file to Aspen
7b4d404 HEAD@{19}: commit: modify the GBSX_script.sh script to correct for 2nd enzyme
317ae1e HEAD@{20}: commit: modify the GBSX_script.sh script
a69b9de HEAD@{21}: commit (amend): trying with PST/MSP in the GBSX test script
502c7cb HEAD@{22}: commit (amend): rying with PST/MSP in the GBSX test script
f7046bc HEAD@{23}: commit: add PST/MSP recog sequence
b9ee79a HEAD@{24}: commit: update gitignore after running RE digest script
5ea495a HEAD@{25}: commit: add GBSX test script
f1e4dbc HEAD@{26}: commit: modify gitignore for fa files
c827fc4 HEAD@{27}: commit (initial): add gitignore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset` allows you to point at any commit, not just `HEAD` or `HEAD^`, so we can use the SHA (leftmost column)

```
git reset 31a3dd2
```

If you want to destroy all of your current changes in the codebase (and not just what commit git is currently pointing to), you can use the `--hard` option.

```
git reset --hard 31a3dd2
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile adding a note about the `--hard` option, which is probably what the OP needs.

Comment: @SomeKittens thanks for the tip. Now i have a clean repository...Will try to use the `reset` bit smartly from now onwards

Comment: @upendra you may have been looking for `git log` instead of `git reflog` ?

Comment: @SomeKittens by clean repository i mean i have destroyed all those unwanted resets and now i am on the commit that i wanted. So everything fine now after the `hard reset`

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use Git GUI to make it instead of Git Bash.

Open **Git GUI**, then open your repository.

Among the menu buttons, click the **"repository"** and select **"show all branches' history"(something like this, I can't give you the accurate name because it's not English on my computer)**. If you didn't work with remote branches, you can just select **"show XXX branch's history"(something like this, too)**.

After your click, a new window whose title starts with "gitk:" will pop out and you can see all the commits you commited in it. Then just **right click the commit that you want to reset to and click "reset XXX branch to here"**.

This is the most intuitionistic way to reset code-version I know. Hope it can help you :)